Can we find the equivalent resistance just by using series and parallel combinations?

Can we calculate the equivalent resistance between \$A\$ and \$B\$ by using just the concept of series and parallel combinations\$?\$


I can solve this by assuming that a battery of voltage \$V\$ is connected across the circuit and the current in the circuit is \$I\$. By using some symmetry and KVL, one can easily find the value of \$\frac{V}{I}\$ or the equivalent resistance.
My friend solved it using the star-delta method (tbh I never understood that method).
But I want to know can this be solved using just series and parallel combination? Any help is greatly appreciated.

I don't think so. Obviously, the vertical  2Ω resistors cannot be eliminated because of the asymmetry so I think you'll need something more.

I strongly suggest you study the star-delta transform, it turns this circuit into a series/parallel string of resistors and makes it trivial to solve.

Math, That looks not so unlike your cube problem, earlier, once it has been simplified. It has a not-dissimilar symmetry, too. (The bottom three resistors are a mirror image of the top three.)
But there are many ways to approach your specific problem, well expressed in Hamlet: "There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio, than are dreamt of in your philosophy." (Act 1, Scene 5.) I'll take a slightly less traveled path below.
Note:

If B is grounded:

Then it must be the case that \$V_\text{D}+V_\text{E}=V_\text{C}+V_\text{F}=V_\text{A}\$ and we can replace \$V_\text{E}\$ and \$V_\text{F}\$, as shown above. That's promising as it's fewer unknowns.
Also, since two of those nodes are voltage sources, we can further reduce the above schematic:

This will immediately eliminate both of the remaining variables: \$V_\text{C}=\frac{3}{4}V_\text{A}\$ and \$V_\text{D}=\frac{5}{8}V_\text{A}\$:
$$\require{cancel}\begin{align*}\frac{V_\text{A}-V_\text{C}}{1\:\Omega}+\frac{V_\text{A}\cancel{-V_\text{D}}-V_\text{C}}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{\cancel{V_\text{D}}-V_\text{C}}{2\:\Omega}&=0\\\\\frac{3}{2}V_\text{A}-2V_\text{C}&=0\\\\V_\text{C}&=\frac34V_\text{A}\\\\\frac{V_\text{A}-V_\text{D}}{3\:\Omega}+\frac{V_\text{A}\cancel{-V_\text{C}}-V_\text{D}}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{\cancel{V_\text{C}}-V_\text{D}}{2\:\Omega}&=0\\\\\frac{5}{6}V_\text{A}-\frac43V_\text{D}&=0\\\\V_\text{D}&=\frac58V_\text{A}
\end{align*}$$
Those two nodes are now voltage sources (again), so reduce the schematic still further to:

And so, looking at the sum of the two currents going from \$V_\text{A}\$ to each of the those two following nodes, and dividing that into \$V_\text{A}\$, the equivalent resistance must be \$\frac83\:\Omega\$:
$$\begin{align*}R_{_\text{TH}} &= \frac{ \cancel{V_\text{A}} }{ \frac{ \cancel{V_\text{A}} - \frac34 \cancel{V_\text{A}} }{1\:\Omega}+\frac{\cancel{V_\text{A}}-\frac58 \cancel{V_\text{A}}}{3\:\Omega}}\\\\&=\frac{1\:\text{V}}{\frac14\:\text{A}+\frac18\:\text{A}}\\\\&=\frac83\:\Omega
\end{align*}$$
One of many alternate ways to add to the pile.

This is really helpful

You might be able to solve this with delta to Y transforms and pi to T transforms, much more difficult than node mesh:


https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-circuit-analysis-topic/ee-resistor-circuits/a/ee-delta-wye-resistor-networks


Can we calculate the equivalent resistance between A and B by using just the concept of series and parallel combinations?

Did you ever feel the urge to shoot a mosquito with a surface-to-air missile? If so, you'd enjoy the following inappropriately overkilled solution using 2-EET.
Extra Element Theorem (EET) is a lesser known circuit analysis technique, original invented by professor R. D. Middlebrook at Caltech for easier pencil-and-paper calculations. Using this theorem, it is possible "ignore" an annoying component by replacing it with an open or short circuit (your choice). Then, several incomplete solutions are calculated separately. Finally, they're combined into the full solution by plugging them into a suitable EET formula.
It can also be generalized to 2-EET and even nEET. When enough components are removed via EET, almost every circuit can be reduced to the simplest form solvable using series and parallel combinations only. EET has its own problems: It allows you to skip the algebra-heavy KVL/KCL analysis, but the final combination step can still be an alphabet soup. In addition, when 2-EET and nEET are used, combinatorial explosion occurs: 2 circuits for EET, 4 circuits for 2-EET, 8 circuits for 3-EET, etc. But for certain types of problems, it can work really well.
This particular problem is not the best example, still, let's try applying 2-EET just for fun.
Step 0: Theory of Null Double Injection
An EET formula takes 3 types of input: a reference transfer function \$ H_\mathrm{ref} \$, and two special kind of impedances called \$ Z_d \$ and \$ Z_n \$. The meanings of these variables and their application to impedance calculation is not self-evident. So it requires an explanation first.
Basically:

\$ H_\mathrm{ref} \$: The transfer function of the circuit, without extra elements.
\$ Z_d \$:  "Single Injection" impedance, an input impedance seen from a different port (where the now-removed extra elements were originally connected across), when the input excitation is switched off.
\$ Z_n \$:  "Null Double Injection" impedance, an input impedance seen from a different port (where the now-removed extra elements were originally connected across), when the input excitation is switched on, but its response is nulled by an equal and opposite signal.

But it doesn't make any sense? Don't worry, the interpretation is a little tricky, but the end result is plain and simple.
Theoretically, EET is a way to find a transfer function \$ H(s) \$ of the circuit that determines its relationship between an excitation \$ E(s) \$ and its response \$ R(s) \$. It can be voltage gain, current gain, transconductance, transimpedance, input impedance, or output impedance.
The definition of an input impedance is:
$$
H(s) = \frac{R(s)}{E(s)} = \frac{V_\mathrm{in}}{I_\mathrm{in}}
$$
According to transfer function formalism: To find a circuit's input impedance, apply a current source excitation as our input, and treat the voltage drop across the same port as our output.
Thus:

\$ H_\mathrm{ref} \$ is simply the input impedance without extra elements.
\$ Z_d \$ is the input impedance measured across the terminals of the (now-removed) extra elements, when the input port is an open circuit - because our excitation current source is switched off. Letter d stands for "drive point". As a mnemonic, it can also mean "different (not the input port)" or "denominator (of the formula)".
\$ Z_n \$  is the input impedance measured across the terminals of the (now-removed) extra elements, when the input port is a short circuit - because our voltage output is nulled at the same port. Letter n stands for "null". As a mnemonic, it can mean "numerator (of the formula)". Note that in general, injecting an equal and opposite signal is not the same thing as shorting the node to ground, but it's true when calculating input impedance.

We can imagine the current excitation input as an ohmmeter, so I'll also denote the
excitation source's internal impedance as \$ Z_\mathrm{meter} \$.
This is enough theory for our purpose.
Step 1: Uninstall Components

Now, let's examine the original circuit. We pick our victims and "remove" them to simplify the circuit. You can remove any component you like, but usually the most "annoying" one. You're also free to choose whether to replace that with an open or short circuit. In 2-EET, one can remove 2 components at the same time, at the expense of using a complicated EET formula.
My decision is to remove R3 and R6 - the original circuit is a complicated bridge, but after their removal, the bridge degrades to simple series-parallel combinations. So, let's denote R3 as the first extra element \$ Z_1 \$, and R6 the second extra element \$ Z_2 \$.
Step 2: Select and Interpret EET Formulas
There are 4 possible (and 3 unique) formulas for 2-EET, depending on the treatment of Z1 and Z2 as open circuits or short circuits. Here, both extra elements are seen as open circuits, so we pick the following formula.
$$
\newcommand{\eetref}[2]
{
    \left. H \middle|_{\substack{Z_1 \to #1 \\ Z_2 \to #2}} \right.
}
\begin{align}
H = \eetref{\infty}{\infty} &\cdot  {{1 + \dfrac{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}}{Z_1} + \dfrac{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty} }{Z_2} + K_n \dfrac{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}}{Z_1} \dfrac{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}{Z_2}} \over {{1 + \dfrac{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}}{Z_1} + \dfrac{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty} }{Z_2} + K_d \dfrac{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}}{Z_1} \dfrac{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}{Z_2} }}} \\[25pt]
\end{align}
$$
In which:
$$
\begin{align}
K_n &= \dfrac{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}}{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}} = \frac{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to 0}}{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}} \\[10pt]
K_d &= \dfrac{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}}{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}} = \frac{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to 0} }{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}} \\
\end{align}
$$
These formulas look intimidating, but there's no need to fear. First, it's designed for solving practical problems, so we always have reference books at hand, it's not an exam question that must be answered from memory. Furthermore, it's the general solution of all linear circuits with two extra elements, they can be reused for all problems, which means the formula is a labor-saving device by embedding difficult algebra into a ready-made template.
Now it's the time to interpret the terms:

\$ \left. H \middle|_{\substack{Z_1 \to \infty \\ Z_2 \to \infty}} \right. \$ : Reference input impedance without extra elements.
\$ Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty} \$: With input open and \$ Z_2 \$ open, impedance at port of (removed) \$ Z_1 \$.
\$ Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty} \$: With input open and \$ Z_1 \$ open, impedance at port of (removed) \$ Z_2 \$.
\$ Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty} \$: With input short and \$ Z_2 \$ open, impedance at port of (removed) \$ Z_1 \$.
\$ Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty} \$: With input short and \$ Z_1 \$ open, impedance at port of (removed) \$ Z_2 \$.
\$ Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0} \$: With input open and \$ Z_2 \$ short, impedance at port of (removed) \$ Z_1 \$.
\$ Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to 0} \$: With input open and \$ Z_1 \$ short, impedance at port of (removed) \$ Z_2 \$ (optional).
\$ Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0} \$: With input short and \$ Z_2 \$ short, impedance at port of (removed) \$ Z_1 \$.
\$ Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to 0} \$: With input short and \$ Z_1 \$ short, impedance at port of (removed) \$ Z_2 \$ (optional).

Note that while the first 5 terms are mandatory, but the last 4 terms are not. It's up to ourselves
to choose between solving for \$ Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0} \$ or \$ Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to 0} \$, and between
solving for \$ Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0} \$ or \$ Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to 0} \$. We always want to choose the
variants that produce easier circuits.
As a reminder again here, letter d stands for "drive point", "different", or
"denominator", and letter n stands for "null" or "numerator". For a self-impedance
calculation, input is current, output is voltage, both are at the same port. To null
the output is to short the output voltage to ground.
Step 3: Obtain All Terms
Step 3.0: Obtain Reference Input Impedance \$ \left. H \middle|_{\substack{Z_1 \to \infty \\ Z_2 \to \infty}} \right. \$

By visual inspection, one can immediately see the solution without extra elements: R1, R4, R7 are in series. R2, R5, R8 are in series. Both chains are in parallel. Thus:
$$
\begin{align}
\left. H \middle|_{\substack{Z_1 \to \infty \\ Z_2 \to \infty}} \right. &= (R1 + R4 + R7) \parallel (R2 + R5 + R8) \\
&= (1 + 2 + 3) \parallel (3 + 2 + 1) \\
&= 3 \text{ }\Omega
\end{align}
$$
Step 3.1: Open Input and Open \$ Z_2 \$, Obtain \$ Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty} \$

By visual inspection: R1, R2 are in series. R4, R7, R5, R8 are in series.
Both chains themselves are in parallel. Thus:
$$
\begin{align}
\left. Z_\mathrm{d1} \middle|_{Z_2 \to \infty} \right. &= (R1 + R2) \parallel (R4 + R7 + R5 + R8) \\
&= (1 + 3) \parallel (2 + 3 + 2 + 1) \\
&= 2.67 \text{ }\Omega
\end{align}
$$
Step 3.2: Open Input and Open \$ Z_1 \$, Obtain \$ Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty} \$

By visual inspection: R7, R8 are in series. R1, R4, R5, R2 are in series.
Both chains themselves are in parallel. Thus:
$$
\begin{align}
\left. Z_\mathrm{d2} \middle|_{Z_1 \to \infty} \right. &= (R7 + R8) \parallel (R1 + R4 + R2 + R5) \\
&= (3 + 1) \parallel (1 + 2 + 3 + 2) \\
&= 2.67 \text{ }\Omega
\end{align}
$$
Step 3.3: Open Input and Short \$ Z_2 \$, Obtain \$ Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0} \$

By visual inspection: R1, R2 are in series. R4, R5 are in series.
Both chains themselves are in parallel. Thus:
$$
\begin{align}
\left. Z_\mathrm{d1} \middle|_{Z_2 \to 0} \right. &= (R1 + R2) \parallel (R4 + R5) \\
&= (1 + 3) \parallel (2 + 2) \\
&= 2 \text{ }\Omega
\end{align}
$$
Step 3.4: Short Input and Open \$ Z_2 \$, Obtain \$ Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty} \$

By visual inspection: R4, R7 are in series, and forms a voltage divider with R1.
R5, R8 are in series, and forms a voltage divider with R2. In a basic voltage
divider, with a shorted input, its mid-point is equivalent to two parallel resistors.
Finally, both voltage divider chains are in series. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\left. Z_\mathrm{n1} \middle|_{Z_2 \to \infty} \right. &= [R1 \parallel (R4 + R7)] + [R2 \parallel (R5 + R8)] \\
&= [1 \parallel (2 + 3)] + [3 \parallel (2 + 1)] \\
&= 2.33 \text{ }\Omega
\end{align}
$$
Step 3.5: Short Input and Open \$ Z_1 \$, Obtain \$ Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty} \$

By visual inspection: R1, R4 are in series, and forms a voltage divider with R7.
R2, R5 are in series, and forms a voltage divider with R8. In a basic voltage
divider, with a shorted input, its mid-point is equivalent to two parallel resistors.
Finally, both voltage divider chains are in series. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\left. Z_\mathrm{n2} \middle|_{Z_1 \to \infty} \right. &= [R7 \parallel (R1 + R4)] + [R8 \parallel (R2 + R5)] \\
&= [3 \parallel (1 + 2)] + [1 \parallel (3 + 2)] \\
&= 2.33 \text{ }\Omega
\end{align}
$$
Step 3.6: Short Input and Short \$ Z_2 \$, Obtain \$ Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0} \$

By visual inspection, we unfortunately found that by shorting both the
input port and \$ Z_2 \$, we recreate a non-trivial bridge circuit
that we have been trying to evade from at great lengths. Its drive-point
impedance cannot be determined by series-parallel combinations, defeating
the very motivation behind EET.
What are our options, then? First, We can often restart our analysis from scratch -
just try again by removing other components, or by using another open-short
combination, or both. Alternatively, the subproblem can be solved using
conventional linear algebra by applying KVL/KCL, we didn't succeed at avoid
algebra but we at least reduced its size. Also, EET itself can be applied
recursively to solve a subproblem that arised from it. But none of it looks
like an appealing option for us.
Step 4: Apply Redundancy Relations to Avoid Difficulties
Fortunately, EET's redundancy relations provide an escape hatch. Because the EET
can be applied in many ways, some impedances are also determinable indirectly
from other variables. As a result, if a quantity is hard to solve, we can solve
for something else. This allows us to swap an open or a short circuit to a more convenient location, so we can pick the easiest one.
In this case, we pick the following redundancy relation:
$$
\newcommand{\eetref}[2]
{
    \left. H \middle|_{\substack{Z_1 \to #1 \\ Z_2 \to #2}} \right.
}
\begin{align}
\eetref{0}{0} \dfrac{Z_\mathrm{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}}{Z_\mathrm{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}} =
\eetref{\infty}{\infty} \dfrac{Z_\mathrm{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}{Z_\mathrm{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}} 
\end{align}
$$
Since we have already obtained \$ \eetref{\infty}{\infty} \$, \$ Z_\mathrm{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0} \$,
\$ Z_\mathrm{d2} |_{Z_2 \to \infty} \$ and \$ Z_\mathrm{n2} |_{Z_2 \to \infty} \$, the quantity
\$ \eetref{0}{0} \$ is all we need. It stands for, "input impedance when extra elements are
shorted out", immediately allowing us to circumvent our previous difficulties.

By visual inspection, R1 and R2 are in parallel, R4 and R5 are in parallel,
R7 and R8 are in parallel.
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
&\eetref{0}{0} \dfrac{Z_\mathrm{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}}{Z_\mathrm{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}} =
\eetref{\infty}{\infty} \dfrac{Z_\mathrm{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}{Z_\mathrm{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}} \\
&\Rightarrow Z_\mathrm{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0} = \dfrac{\eetref{0}{0} Z_\mathrm{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0} }{\eetref{\infty}{\infty} \dfrac{Z_\mathrm{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}{Z_\mathrm{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}} \\
&\Rightarrow Z_\mathrm{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0} = \dfrac{[(R1 \parallel R2) + (R4 \parallel R5) + (R7 \parallel R8)] \cdot 2}{3 \cdot \dfrac{2.33}{2.67}} \\
&\Rightarrow Z_\mathrm{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0} = \dfrac{2.5 \cdot 2}{3 \cdot \dfrac{2.33}{2.67}} = 1.91\text{ }\Omega
\end{align}
$$
Step 5: Combine all Partial Results Together
All the necessary calculations for 2-EET are complete. Finally, these results
are combined by plugging the equations or numbers back into an appropriate 2-EET
formula.
Numerical Solution
Immediately, a numerical solution is obtained via 2-EET.
Calculate coefficient \$K_n\$:
$$
\begin{align}
K_n &= \dfrac{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}}{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}} = \frac{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to 0}}{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}} \\[10pt]
&= \frac{1.91}{2.33} = 0.82
\end{align}
$$
Calculate coefficient \$ K_d \$:
$$
\begin{align}
K_d &= \dfrac{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}}{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}} = \frac{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to 0} }{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}} \\
&= \frac{2}{2.67} = 0.75
\end{align}
$$
One last step, apply the 2-EET formula:
$$
\newcommand{\eetref}[2]
{
    \left. H \middle|_{\substack{Z_1 \to #1 \\ Z_2 \to #2}} \right.
}
\begin{align}
H &= \eetref{\infty}{\infty} \cdot  {{1 + \dfrac{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}}{Z_1} + \dfrac{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty} }{Z_2} + K_n \dfrac{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}}{Z_1} \dfrac{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}{Z_2}} \over {{1 + \dfrac{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}}{Z_1} + \dfrac{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty} }{Z_2} + K_d \dfrac{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}}{Z_1} \dfrac{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}{Z_2} }}} \\[25pt]
H &= 3 \cdot  {{1 + \dfrac{2.33}{2} + \dfrac{2.33}{2} + 0.82 \cdot \dfrac{2.33}{2} \dfrac{2.33}{2}} \over {{1 + \dfrac{2.67}{2} + \dfrac{2.67}{2} + 0.75 \cdot \dfrac{2.67}{2} \dfrac{2.67}{2} }}} \\
&= 3 \cdot \frac{4.44}{5.00} = 2.66\text{ }\Omega
\end{align}
$$
Analytic Solution
The true strength of the EET is that it allows one to derive long and complicated
analytic transfer functions in a modular and piecewise manner. The algebra needed
in each substep is minimized, all heavy algebra is postponed at the last step.
The following equations give the exact solution to the original circuits with
arbitrary impedances.
$$
\newcommand{\eetref}[2]
{
    \left. H \middle|_{\substack{Z_1 \to #1 \\ Z_2 \to #2}} \right.
}
\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
H &= \eetref{\infty}{\infty} \cdot  {{1 + \dfrac{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}}{R_3} + \dfrac{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty} }{R_6} + K_n \dfrac{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}}{R_3} \dfrac{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}{R_6}} \over {{1 + \dfrac{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}}{R_3} + \dfrac{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty} }{R_6} + K_d \dfrac{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}}{R_3} \dfrac{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}{R_6} }}} \\
\eetref{\infty}{\infty} &= (R1 + R4 + R7) \parallel (R2 + R5 + R8) \\
\eetref{0}{0} &= [(R1 \parallel R2) + (R4 \parallel R5) + (R7 \parallel R8)] \\
\left. Z_\mathrm{d1} \middle|_{Z_2 \to \infty} \right. &= (R1 + R2) \parallel (R4 + R7 + R5 + R8) \\
\left. Z_\mathrm{d2} \middle|_{Z_1 \to \infty} \right. &= (R7 + R8) \parallel (R1 + R4 + R2 + R5) \\
\left. Z_\mathrm{n1} \middle|_{Z_2 \to \infty} \right. &= [R1 \parallel (R4 + R7)] + [R2 \parallel (R5 + R8)] \\
\left. Z_\mathrm{n2} \middle|_{Z_1 \to \infty} \right. &= [R7 \parallel (R1 + R4)] + [R8 \parallel (R2 + R5)] \\
\left. Z_\mathrm{d1} \middle|_{Z_2 \to 0} \right. &= (R1 + R2) \parallel (R4 + R5) \\
Z_\mathrm{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0} &= \dfrac{\eetref{0}{0} Z_\mathrm{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0} }{\eetref{\infty}{\infty} \dfrac{Z_\mathrm{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}{Z_\mathrm{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}} \\
K_n &= \dfrac{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}}{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}} = \frac{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to 0}}{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}} \\
K_d &= \dfrac{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}}{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}} = \frac{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to 0} }{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
$$
By standing on the shoulder of the giants and applying the "canned formulas" of 2-EET,
we've completely solved the original circuit using series and parallel combinations only,
without using linear algebra even once!
Step 6: Correctness Verification
To ensure the results obtained via 2-EET is absolutely valid, first, we can perform computerized
symbolic circuit analysis using Lcapy via
the following Python code:
from lcapy import Circuit

circuit = ("""
    R1 1 2
    R2 3 4
    R3 2 4
    R4 2 5
    R5 4 6
    R6 5 6
    R7 5 7
    R8 6 8
    W1 7 8
    W2 1 3
    W3 1 9
    W4 7 10
    P1 9 10
""")

print(str(circuit.impedance("P1")))

The output of the program is:
(R1*R2*R3*R6 + R1*R2*R3*R7 + R1*R2*R3*R8 + R1*R2*R4*R6 + R1*R2*R4*R7 + R1*R2*R
4*R8 + R1*R2*R5*R6 + R1*R2*R5*R7 + R1*R2*R5*R8 + R1*R2*R6*R7 + R1*R2*R6*R8 + R
1*R3*R5*R6 + R1*R3*R5*R7 + R1*R3*R5*R8 + R1*R3*R6*R8 + R1*R3*R7*R8 + R1*R4*R5*
R6 + R1*R4*R5*R7 + R1*R4*R5*R8 + R1*R4*R6*R8 + R1*R4*R7*R8 + R1*R5*R6*R7 + R1*
R5*R7*R8 + R1*R6*R7*R8 + R2*R3*R4*R6 + R2*R3*R4*R7 + R2*R3*R4*R8 + R2*R3*R6*R7
 + R2*R3*R7*R8 + R2*R4*R5*R6 + R2*R4*R5*R7 + R2*R4*R5*R8 + R2*R4*R6*R8 + R2*R4
*R7*R8 + R2*R5*R6*R7 + R2*R5*R7*R8 + R2*R6*R7*R8 + R3*R4*R5*R6 + R3*R4*R5*R7 +
 R3*R4*R5*R8 + R3*R4*R6*R8 + R3*R4*R7*R8 + R3*R5*R6*R7 + R3*R5*R7*R8 + R3*R6*R
7*R8)/(R1*R3*R6 + R1*R3*R7 + R1*R3*R8 + R1*R4*R6 + R1*R4*R7 + R1*R4*R8 + R1*R5
*R6 + R1*R5*R7 + R1*R5*R8 + R1*R6*R7 + R1*R6*R8 + R2*R3*R6 + R2*R3*R7 + R2*R3*
R8 + R2*R4*R6 + R2*R4*R7 + R2*R4*R8 + R2*R5*R6 + R2*R5*R7 + R2*R5*R8 + R2*R6*R
7 + R2*R6*R8 + R3*R4*R6 + R3*R4*R7 + R3*R4*R8 + R3*R5*R6 + R3*R5*R7 + R3*R5*R8
 + R3*R6*R7 + R3*R6*R8)

Then, we use SageMath, a free and open Computer Algebra System, to expand our own
2-EET solution and compare our solution with the "ground truth" from Lcapy:
from sage.all import *

def parallel(x, y):
    return 1 / ((1 / x) + (1 / y))

var("R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8")

H_inf_inf = parallel(R1 + R4 + R7, R2 + R5 + R8)
H_zero_zero = parallel(R1, R2) + parallel(R4, R5) + parallel(R7, R8)
Zd1_z2inf = parallel(R1 + R2, R4 + R7 + R5 + R8)
Zd2_z1inf = parallel(R7 + R8, R1 + R4 + R2 + R5)
Zn1_z2inf = parallel(R1, R4 + R7) + parallel(R2, R5 + R8)
Zn2_z1inf = parallel(R7, R1 + R4) + parallel(R8, R2 + R5)
Zd1_z2zero = parallel(R1 + R2, R4 + R5)
Zn1_z2zero = (H_zero_zero * Zd1_z2zero) / (H_inf_inf * (Zn2_z1inf / Zd2_z1inf))
Kn = Zn1_z2zero / Zn1_z2inf
Kd = Zd1_z2zero / Zd1_z2inf

eet_solution = H_inf_inf * (
    (1 + (Zn1_z2inf / R3) + (Zn2_z1inf / R6) + Kn * (Zn1_z2inf / R3) * (Zn2_z1inf / R6))
    /
    (1 + (Zd1_z2inf / R3) + (Zd2_z1inf / R6) + Kd * (Zd1_z2inf / R3) * (Zd2_z1inf / R6))
)

lcapy_solution = (R1*R2*R3*R6 + R1*R2*R3*R7 + R1*R2*R3*R8 + R1*R2*R4*R6 + R1*R2*R4*R7 + R1*R2*R4*R8 + R1*R2*R5*R6 + R1*R2*R5*R7 + R1*R2*R5*R8 + R1*R2*R6*R7 + R1*R2*R6*R8 + R1*R3*R5*R6 + R1*R3*R5*R7 + R1*R3*R5*R8 + R1*R3*R6*R8 + R1*R3*R7*R8 + R1*R4*R5*R6 + R1*R4*R5*R7 + R1*R4*R5*R8 + R1*R4*R6*R8 + R1*R4*R7*R8 + R1*R5*R6*R7 + R1*R5*R7*R8 + R1*R6*R7*R8 + R2*R3*R4*R6 + R2*R3*R4*R7 + R2*R3*R4*R8 + R2*R3*R6*R7 + R2*R3*R7*R8 + R2*R4*R5*R6 + R2*R4*R5*R7 + R2*R4*R5*R8 + R2*R4*R6*R8 + R2*R4*R7*R8 + R2*R5*R6*R7 + R2*R5*R7*R8 + R2*R6*R7*R8 + R3*R4*R5*R6 + R3*R4*R5*R7 + R3*R4*R5*R8 + R3*R4*R6*R8 + R3*R4*R7*R8 + R3*R5*R6*R7 + R3*R5*R7*R8 + R3*R6*R7*R8)/(R1*R3*R6 + R1*R3*R7 + R1*R3*R8 + R1*R4*R6 + R1*R4*R7 + R1*R4*R8 + R1*R5*R6 + R1*R5*R7 + R1*R5*R8 + R1*R6*R7 + R1*R6*R8 + R2*R3*R6 + R2*R3*R7 + R2*R3*R8 + R2*R4*R6 + R2*R4*R7 + R2*R4*R8 + R2*R5*R6 + R2*R5*R7 + R2*R5*R8 + R2*R6*R7 + R2*R6*R8 + R3*R4*R6 + R3*R4*R7 + R3*R4*R8 + R3*R5*R6 + R3*R5*R7 + R3*R5*R8 + R3*R6*R7 + R3*R6*R8)

print(bool(eet_solution == lcapy_solution))

This program outputs:
True

For completeness, the simplified full solution can be obtained via:
print(latex(eet_solution.full_simplify()))

This produces:
$$
\frac{{\left(R_{1} R_{2} R_{3} + {\left(R_{1} R_{2} + R_{2} R_{3}\right)} R_{4} + {\left(R_{1} R_{2} + R_{1} R_{3} + {\left(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}\right)} R_{4}\right)} R_{5}\right)} R_{6} + {\left(R_{1} R_{2} R_{3} + {\left(R_{1} R_{2} + R_{2} R_{3}\right)} R_{4} + {\left(R_{1} R_{2} + R_{1} R_{3} + {\left(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}\right)} R_{4}\right)} R_{5} + {\left(R_{1} R_{2} + R_{2} R_{3} + {\left(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}\right)} R_{5}\right)} R_{6}\right)} R_{7} + {\left(R_{1} R_{2} R_{3} + {\left(R_{1} R_{2} + R_{2} R_{3}\right)} R_{4} + {\left(R_{1} R_{2} + R_{1} R_{3} + {\left(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}\right)} R_{4}\right)} R_{5} + {\left(R_{1} R_{2} + R_{1} R_{3} + {\left(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}\right)} R_{4}\right)} R_{6} + {\left({\left(R_{1} + R_{2}\right)} R_{3} + {\left(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}\right)} R_{4} + {\left(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}\right)} R_{5} + {\left(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}\right)} R_{6}\right)} R_{7}\right)} R_{8}}{{\left({\left(R_{1} + R_{2}\right)} R_{3} + {\left(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}\right)} R_{4} + {\left(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}\right)} R_{5}\right)} R_{6} + {\left({\left(R_{1} + R_{2}\right)} R_{3} + {\left(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}\right)} R_{4} + {\left(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}\right)} R_{5} + {\left(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}\right)} R_{6}\right)} R_{7} + {\left({\left(R_{1} + R_{2}\right)} R_{3} + {\left(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}\right)} R_{4} + {\left(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}\right)} R_{5} + {\left(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}\right)} R_{6}\right)} R_{8}}
$$
Clearly, this full formula is difficult to read and use, even after simplification. Proponents of EET call these formulas High-Entropy Expressions, which means all terms are in a diffused and disordered state like gas molecules in a room once a container is opened. The piecewise nature of the solution via 2-EET doesn't give a full answer right away, but it's not really a disadvantage from a usability perspective.
For simpler problems, the best results are often obtained via 1-EET. The extra element appears as a correction term to the original incomplete circuit, and the impact of an extra element is directly readable from the EET equation (Unfortunately, solutions from 2-EET and nEET don't fully benefit from 1-EET's advantage).
Appendix 1: Full EET and 2-EET Formulas
2-EET
For 2-EET, there are 4 possible formulas, depending on the treatment of \$ Z_1 \$ and \$ Z_2 \$ as
open circuits or short circuits, see [3]. Because \$ Z_1 \$ and \$ Z_2 \$ are interchangeable when one
is an open circuit and another is a short circuit, only 3 formulas are unique.
The original paper used gain symbol \$ A \$ to denote a transfer function, but I used \$ H \$ to show that these formulas are general.
$$
\newcommand{\eetref}[2]
{
\left. H  \middle|_{\substack{Z_1 \to #1 \\ Z_2 \to #2}} \right.
}
\begin{align}
H = \eetref{\infty}{\infty} &\cdot  {{1 + \dfrac{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}}{Z_1} + \dfrac{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty} }{Z_2} + K_n \dfrac{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}}{Z_1} \dfrac{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}{Z_2}} \over {{1 + \dfrac{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}}{Z_1} + \dfrac{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty} }{Z_2} + K_d \dfrac{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}}{Z_1} \dfrac{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}{Z_2} }}} \\[25pt]
H = \eetref{0}{0} &\cdot  {{1 + \dfrac{Z_1}{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}} + \dfrac{Z_2}{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to 0} } + K_n \dfrac{Z_1}{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}} \dfrac{Z_2}{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to 0}}} \over {{1 + \dfrac{Z_1}{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}} + \dfrac{Z_2}{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to 0}} + K_d \dfrac{Z_1}{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}} \dfrac{Z_2}{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to 0}}}}} \\[25pt]
H = \eetref{\infty}{0} &\cdot  {{1 + \dfrac{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}}{Z_1} + \dfrac{Z_2}{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}} + \dfrac{1}{K_n} \dfrac{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}}{Z_1} \dfrac{Z_2}{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}} \over {{1 + \dfrac{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}}{Z_1} + \dfrac{Z_2}{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty} } + \dfrac{1}{K_d} \dfrac{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}}{Z_1} \dfrac{Z_2}{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}} }}} 
\end{align}
$$
Parameters \$ K_n \$ and \$ K_d \$ can be interpreted as an "interaction factor" between two extra components themselves. They're given by:
$$
\begin{align}
K_n &= \dfrac{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}}{Z_{n1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}} = \frac{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to 0}}{Z_{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}} \\[10pt]
K_d &= \dfrac{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}}{Z_{d1} |_{Z_2 \to \infty}} = \frac{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to 0} }{Z_{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}} \\
\end{align}
$$
K is close to unity when interaction between two extra elements themselves are small. If the drive-point impedance of one extra element remains the same regardless of whether another extra element is opened or shorted, it obviously proves that they have no interaction, so \$ K_n = K_d = 1 \$. In this case, 2-EET formulas become equivalent to applying 1-EET twice.
Furthermore, the following redundant relation exists. One can use them to avoid
a difficult impedance calculation:
$$
\newcommand{\eetref}[2]
{
\left. H \middle|_{\substack{Z_1 \to #1 \\ Z_2 \to #2}} \right.
}
\begin{align}
\eetref{\infty}{0} =
\eetref{0}{0} \dfrac{Z_\mathrm{d1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}}{Z_\mathrm{n1} |_{Z_2 \to 0}} =
\eetref{\infty}{\infty} \dfrac{Z_\mathrm{n2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}}{Z_\mathrm{d2} |_{Z_1 \to \infty}} 
\end{align}
$$
This allows us to swap an open or a short circuit to a more convenient port, so we can pick the easiest one.
1-EET
For basic EET, the influence of a single extra element is determined from 3 calculations only, using 2 formulas for an open circuit or a short circuit. Note how these 1-EET formulas are 2-EET formulas' degenerated forms.
$$
\newcommand{\eetref}[1]
{
\left. H  \middle|_{Z_1 \to #1} \right.
}
\begin{align}
H = \eetref{\infty} \cdot
&\dfrac
{
1 + \dfrac{Z_{n1}}{Z_1}
}
{
1 + \dfrac{Z_{d1}}{Z_1}
} \\[15pt]
H = \eetref{0} \cdot
&\dfrac
{
1 + \dfrac{Z_1}{Z_{n1}}
}
{
1 + \dfrac{Z_1}{Z_{d1}}
} \\
\end{align}
$$
with the following redundant relation:
$$
\newcommand{\eetref}[1]
{
\left. H  \middle|_{Z_1 \to #1} \right.
}
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\eetref{0}}{\eetref{\infty}} = \dfrac{Z_{n1}}{Z_{d1}}
\end{align}
$$
This allows us to swap an open or a short circuit to a more convenient port.
Bibliography

Vorpérian, Vatché. Fast analytical techniques for electrical and electronic circuits. Cambridge University Press, 2002. Make sure to check the introductory Wheatstone bridge example at here.

Basso, Christophe P. Linear circuit transfer functions: An introduction to fast analytical techniques. John Wiley & Sons, 2016.

Middlebrook, R. D. The two extra element theorem. Proc. IEEE 21st Annu. Frontiers in Education Conference. 1991.



I really appreciate the fact that you wrote so much...not everyone does that :)

Although my following answer does not satisfy the request of the asker, I think that, in any case, the circuit analysis I performed in three different classical ways is still useful. (the negative signs indicate that the current or voltage is opposite to that chosen in the digraph, for this reason the ratios can be negative, at least until proven otherwise):


This particular circuit can't be solved by (repeatedly) replacing with series/parallel combinations.
Also, in general you'll need to solve star/delta for more than 3 elements.
